# Is there a ChoiceType to allow the user to only select one choice from a list of choices in Symfony?

Tags: symfony4, symfony5

I tried this, but it allows the user to select both choices, I only want to allow the user to select one role

```
            ->add("role", ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Technician' => 'technician',
                'Client' => 'client'
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are using checkboxes. You have to turn them into radio buttons by setting the option `expanded` to `true` and `multiple` to `false`. Details [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons).

```php
$builder->add(
    'role', 
    ChoiceType::class, [
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'choices' => [
            'Technician' => 'technician',
            'Client' => 'client'
        ]
    ]
);
```